# Difference between two ways of setting a button's initial state

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've found out that I have two ways to set a button initial "enabled" property value. First one: Utilities -> Button -> State Config. Second one is inside `ViewController.swift` overriding the method `viewWillAppear`:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        // RIGHT HERE
        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

            myButton.enabled = true
        } 
}
```

So, is there an actual difference? Or in the end they are the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Both give same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure a property through Interface Builder, the task of performing the configuration is performed by the library that reads the corresponding storyboard or the NIB file. This is done at the time the content of the interface description file is processed, without you having to write any additional code.

When you configure a property by overriding `viewWillAppear` method, the configuration is performed in your code.

Once the configuration has been performed, there is no way to distinguish between the two: the results look the same, because the button is in the same state. A common rule of thumb to decide between the two is as follows:

- When you define a UI element visually, you should set as many properties in the editor as you can.
- When you define a UI element visually, but the value of the property is not known at design time (for example, because you need to check a file before deciding whether to enable a button or not) you need to configure the property programmatically.
- When you define a UI element programmatically, you have no other choice but to set properties programmatically.